# WinForms App Version Number - AssemblyInformation different from ControlPanel Information

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, version, assemblyinfo

I have a problem ,  I change the Version number in the `Properties`-`Application`-`Assembly Information`  in Visual Studio.

But in Control Panel - Program and Features in the Version Column it shows all the time 1.0.0.

But when I right-Click on the icon of the installed `WinForms` App after the build in Properties it says the version that I have put previous in Visual Studio.

How can I make it to be the same as it is in the Assembly Information?

Comment: Set the **File** version.

Comment: [AssemblyVersionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.-ctor) -- [AssemblyFileVersionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.-ctor)

Comment: @JQSOFT, I have already set the file version  and the assembly version via properties but the problem remains

Comment: This answer can be of help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337338/c-sharp-net-apps-product-version-not-updating-in-control-panel-program-u)

Comment: Can't tell. Try enabling the `RemovePreviousVersions` property. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600596/visual-studio-setup-project-doesnt-upgrade-to-new-program)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222243/set-assemblyinfo-version-numbers-with-msi-setup-version) are useful.

Comment: @LopDev, the version in control panel is equal to the publish version in visual studio, please check it.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT, that is not true for this case . The version continues to be 1.0.0 in Control Panel-Program and Features after the build and Install of the app , despite the fact that I have change the version and the file version (generally everything that says ...version ) in the Properties Assembly Information in Visual Studio.    But the problem remains

Comment: @LopDev, you misunderstand me. You can compare in vs publish -> publish version and    in control panel app version. It is not related to the file version and assembly version you mentioned.